# ScrollTop on with ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Is there any way to scroll to top of the grid when search result populated, i have one textbox after entering text the function is called and all the values related to the text entered populates in grid after scrolling down to grid and entering new search term grid should scroll to top.

> Here is grid

```
 $scope.gridOptionsSearchedPatient = {
    columnDefs: [
        {
            name: 'Last Name',
            field: 'PatientLastName'
        }, {
            name: 'First Name',
            field: 'PatientFirstName'
        }, {
            name: 'Account Number',
            field: 'AccountNumber'
        }
    ]
};
```

> Here is the function I call on textbox

```
$scope.getData = function(){
   //code to find searched term result
$http.get("some_url").then(function(data){
    $scope.gridOptionsSearchedPatient.data = data;
});
}
```

Please suggest me what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

`$scope.gridApi.core.scrollTo( 
      $scope.gridOptions.data[rowIndex],
      $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[colIndex]
)`

Example is on the page: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/202_cellnav